# IMFMediaSink, how to set an encoder property?

Tags: c++, encoding, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I have a IMFMediaSink interface implemented that encodes through the native h264 codec a particular source (we're talking about the Windows 8 Modern (Metro) interface). I want to change the default options of the h264 codec, how to do that?

I searched online and I kind of understand that the ICodecAPI interface is something related to what I want to do, but how to use it? Does anyone have some sample code to look at to try and understand what to do?

I know I can use the MF_SINK_WRITER_ENCODER_CONFIG for a sinkwriter, but I'm not using that class unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hey,
>   I did hear back from our architect. He cofirmed that the current implientation is "by design". The team is aware of the limitaion but I'm not sure if they will be able to consider a design change.
>   I hope this helps,
>   James

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/74f02476-05aa-4520-8ee6-1b794321173e/how-to-access-icodec-property?forum=winappswithhtml5

I found the solution myself. It doesn't exist a way to access ICodecAPI from WinRT Metro. This is by design and Microsoft don't think will change it anytime soon. It's a shame...:(

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

Try getting an `IMFStreamSink` on your h264 stream from the `IMFMediaSink`. `GetStremSinkCount` and `GetStreamSinkByIndex` should help you on that.

Then call `GetMediaTypeHandler` on `IMFMediaSink` object.
Call `GetCurrentMediaType` on `IMFMediaTypeHandler`.
Now you should have a pointer to an `IMFMediaType`, which is derived from the `IMFAttributes`. You should be able to configure your transformer here.

Comment: I will give it a try later this week. I didn't think I could pass the parameters directly through the media type...if it works it's great...

Comment: Can you provide more info on what have you tried and what failed with what error code?

Comment: No error code whatsoever, the system simply ignores the new parameter. 

This is a command that works :

spMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Base); 

while this does nothing :

spMediaType->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed, 0); 

I tried both in the same place and anything that starts with CODECAPI is ignored while the normal Media Type values are working.

Comment: My answer implies using Media Type. Btw, anything you need to set on the transformer can be done through the Media Type. I still don't understand what exactly are you not able to set?

Comment: All the options of the encoder aren't available in the media type. You need to access the backend encoder or you can't choose stuff like CABAC (high profile), speedvsquality, VBR or CBR, etc...

Comment: You are wrong. For example, you can set main profile (or any other, assuming that it's supported on your OS) with this call: SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Main);

Comment: That's because that's not a CODECAPI options. I want to be able to set options from the CodecAPI enumeration like CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed.

Comment: Any particular reason for codec API? Did you ever try to call ICodecAPI::IsSupported() on CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed for the H264? I wouldn't be surprised if it's not supported. I'll repeat for the last time, you can set all necessary params through the media type. On prior to Win 8 some settings are read only, like distance between two key frames, btu still, fully functional.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It is compatible as far as this document says. I tried tons of them, all of them are not working. The reason I need them is to be able to change the encoding mode from VBR to Quality based.

How am I supposed to run that ICodecAPI::IsSupported if I don't have any class derived from ICodecAPI to run that against in the first place? That's what I'm trying to get in the first place...*facepalm*

I know how to do this OUTSIDE Metro/Modern, the problem is how to do it within the Modern interface of Windows 8+.

Comment: CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed is the thing as CODECAPI_AVEncVideoEncodeQP. What happens when you try to set quality encoding through the  SetGUID(CODECAPI_AVEncVideoEncodeQP...)? Also, I don't see how is metro style related to seeting the H264 encoder. It should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69965/discussion-between-feal87-and-guest).